# Value from cell to ActiveX Combobox on Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have list of employees that I update and that's why I would like to gather names by VBA:

```
Private Sub CommercialBox_DropButtonClick()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim RngCom As Range

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").CommercialBox.Clear
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact database")
    For Each RngCom In .Range("B61:B77")
        If RngCom.Value <> vbNullString Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").CommercialBox.AddItem RngCom.Value
    Next RngCom
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is connected to `DropButtonClick` and works fine. 
Now I need to connect also cell value to dropdown box so user will see what he has chosen. There is a small time gap between code is entering value to Worksheet. That's why this code does not work really:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").CommercialBox.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact database").Range("I109").Value
End Sub
```

I have tried also this way, but it more like workaround than correct solution:

```
Private Sub CommercialBox_LostFocus()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").CommercialBox.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact database").Range("I109").Value
End Sub
```

How to repair that issue?

Comment: `ListFillRange` and `LinkedCell` properties are designed for both tasks: filling combobox list and linking its value to a cell without a single line of code, what is the reason of not using them?

Comment: `ListFillRange` can't be dynamic I guess? It can't pick values from range that "are not empty"

Comment: It can be dynamic named range, not sure if it would work in this case. But the main question is about linking value with a cell, so why not LinkedCell?

Comment: I need to "pick values" on `Private Sub CommercialBox_DropButtonClick()`

Comment: OK, I understand why you fill the list in the event handler, but I still do not know why setting `LinkedCell` to "I109" would not work for the issue you are trying to solve in the question.